# MarkLogic Optic API from-sql binding parameters

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-optic-api

I'm trying to use the Optic API using from-sql and XQuery. I'm finding it's a great way to get the data I need but I'm trying to find clear examples of passing parameters to placeholders using op:from-sql.

For example

```
let $result := op:from-sql('
                  SELECT name, sum(value) 
                  FROM db.namevalue
                  WHERE client=''IBM''
                    and department in (''IT'', ''ACCOUNTS'')
                  GROUP BY name
                  ORDER BY 2 DESC
                  limit 30
               ')
             => op:result()
return $result
```

works nicely and gives the results I expect.

What I need though it to parameterize so i can use variables instead of literals.
I have seen the op:param but I suspect it isn't used to specify placeholders like the ? in traditional SQL environments.

eg  which I know is wrong;

```
let $client  = "IBM
let $dept    = ("IT", "ACCOUNT")

let $result := op:from-sql('
                  SELECT name, sum(value) 
                  FROM db.namevalue
                  WHERE client=?
                    and department in (?)
                  GROUP BY name
                  ORDER BY 2 DESC
                  limit 30
               ')
             => op:result((), map:entry("$1", $client) => map:entry("$2", $dept))
return $result
```

So is there an clear example of how i can do this?

Thanks,

Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work to use @ as the prefix in the SQL string?  As in:

```
op:from-sql('
              SELECT name, sum(value) 
              FROM db.namevalue
              WHERE client=@client and department in (@department)
              GROUP BY name
              ORDER BY 2 DESC
              limit 30
           ')
         => op:result((),
             map:entry("client", $client)
             => map:with("department", $dept))
```

An alternative would be to express the fixed structure with Optic builder methods and to parameterize the entire SQL condition along the lines of the following untested sketch:

```
op:from-view('db', 'namevalue')
    => op:where(op:sql-condition(op:param("condition")))
    => op:group-by("name", op:sum("valueSum", "value"))
    => op:order-by(op:desc("valueSum"))
    => op:limit(30)
    => op:result((), map:entry("condition", $condition))
```

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Looks like neither works. the @just returns **declare variable $clientId external; -- Undefined external variable fn:QName("","clientId")**

Comment: and the second example returns **XDMP-AS: (err:XPTY0004) $expression as xs:string -- Invalid coercion: map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>) as xs:string**

Comment: The @ error occurs for me on a mismatch between the @name embedded in the SQL string and the name in the map with the bindings. When the names are different, I get the same error.  When the names are the same, I don't get the error.
The 2nd example seems to be a bug in op:sql-condition().